# Finger print skeletonization without using matlab functions

Tags: image-processing, matlab, morphological-operations, image-analysis

I am trying to thin foreground pixels of a finger print until they are one pixel wide without using the built in bwmorph and thin operations.

Can anyone explain to me how to write them in matlab without actually using the built in function. Thanks.

Comment: The conditions used by the matlab implementation are enumerated in the algorithms sections of the bwmorph page http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html#f1-500491

Comment: You need to put some effort into researching the problem before asking people on this site how to do your work for you. What have you tried so far?